# perform testing for Fragments

Tags: android, testing, fragment

I want to test Fragment.I am able to test Instrumentation test only. I want to perform click and set values for the textview. How can it is possible. Here is my code.Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

```
 @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
 public class LearnFactAdditionTest extends 
  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
 private MainActivity testingActivity;
  private Learn_FactsFragment testFragment;

public LearnFactAdditionTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();


    testingActivity = getActivity();

    testFragment = new Learn_FactsFragment();
    testingActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag,testFragment,null).commit();

    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
}

@Test
public void testGameFragmentsTextViews() {

    String empty = "";

    TextView textView = (TextView)testFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.txt_first_num_add);
    assertTrue("Empty stuff", (textView.getText().equals(empty)));
}

public void testMainThread_operations() {
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.txt_first_num_add))
            .perform(ViewActions.typeText("Hi"));
}
}
```

I am getting error like this
No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

Here is my gradle
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g" // 2g should be also OK
}

 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.github.jinatonic.confetti:confetti:1.1.0'
compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'


androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

}
```

Comment: build,gradle plz.

Comment: i suspect Your test runner is not derived from AndroidJUnitRunner

Comment: androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
iadded this for my gradle

Comment: post ur entire build.gradle not ur library part

Comment: i added entire gradle file above

Comment: did u register instrumentation into the AndroidManifest file ??

Comment: u can register in manifest or u can mention ur test runner in the gradle,any one method u follow and u will stop getting this issue

Comment: not register in manifest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157658/discussion-between-avinash-roy-and-gowthami).